# Middleman remove .html extension, but keep http://example.com/about.html valid

Tags: html, ruby, middleman, static-site

I added following line inside my `config.rb` file in order to get rid of `.html` extension so `http://example.com/about.html` becomes `http://example.com/about` and from looking inside a `build` folder I can see that what this does is create a separate directory for each file with its name so `about/index.html` for `about.html` page. This means that if website is accessed with `http://example.com/about.html` such page will not be found and what I'd expect to happen is a redirect to `http://example.com/about` or at least serve relevant page and keep url uncleaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the only way to get what you're looking for is by tackling this through your web server. One option:

**config.rb**

```
require 'rack/middleman/optional_html'
  use Rack::OptionalHtml,
    root: '/example_domain/source',
    urls: %w[/]
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'optional_html', :git => 'https://github.com/tommysundstrom/middleman-rack-optional-html.git'
```

**_nav.html.erb**

```
<nav>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
</nav>
```

**example.com.conf** (add this to your nginx server block)

```
location / { try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html /fallback.html; }
location = /fallback.html { }
```

**layout.erb** (If you wanted to use canonical urls)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><%= current_page.data.title %></title>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/<%= current_page.path.chomp('index.html').chomp('.html').chomp('/') %>"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Just an additional note. Having example.com/about.html redirect to example.com/about is not possible via middleman due to the fact that middleman is only using ruby locally to generate a static site which you would upload to your server. That's where nginx would come in to handle the .html extension and if needed do the 301 redirect from about.html to about. However, if you're more concerned about search engines indexing the correct page I think a better option would be to not do the 301's since that could get messy depending on how large your site is, using a canonical url might work best.